# ADODB.Recordset :Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb, recordset

I am trying to update the column in specific field i.e logouttime based on emp_name and current date.
If current date and emp_name not found then it should shows msg.

I used Recordset.EOF but it gives error on this line.

```
  Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
  Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
  Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
  Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect


  'Create RecordSet
  Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
  With Recordset

'Filter Data
Dim emp_name As Variant
emp_name = Replace(Application.UserName, ",", "")
Source = "UPDATE timetbl Set logouttime =#" & tmp & "#  where empname =  '" & emp_name & "' and c_date=#" & Date & "#"
.Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
If Recordset.EOF = False Then 'error is here
   MsgBox "Please Login first"
Else
    'My code is here
End If
```

Comment: What recordset output are you expecting out of an `UPDATE` statement? Consider using a `Command` for this; no `Recordset` needs to get involved.

Comment: Also, [meet Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) -- using a parameterized `Command` would fix that. As it stands, `Ryan O'Connor` can't log into your system.

Comment: Don't use reserved words as names for anything. `Recordset` is a reserved word, use a different name for variable. There is no code to open recordset. However, I agree, not seeing any purpose for recordset in this code. What if user logout is next day? A record will not be found. Search for record where `logouttime IS NULL`.